# Composer class not found even if it exists

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen, autoloader

I'm developing a Laravel package but I have a problem with composer autoloading.
My package has 2 folders under `src` folder. One of them is named `Laravel` and the other one is `Telegram`. Here is the package structure:

```
./packages
.../typhoon
...../src
......./Laravel
........./Providers
............LumenServiceProvider.php
............LaravelServiceProvider.php
......./Telegram
..........Api.php
.....composer.json
```

This package is developed under `SaliBhdr/Typhoon` namespace.

I have added the `packages/typhoon/src` directory in Laravel's composer file like so:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "SaliBhdr\\Typhoon\\" : "packages/typhoon/src/"
        }
    },
```

And add the `src/` address in package composer.json file like so:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "SaliBhdr\\Typhoon\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

Here is the strange behavior begins. When I execute the `php artisan serve` command Laravel throws an error that says :

```
 Class 'Salibhdr\Typhoon\Laravel\Providers\LumenServiceProvider' not found
```

And if I check if the class exists with `class_exists('Salibhdr\Typhoon\Laravel\Providers\LumenServiceProvider')` function it returns `false`. But if I check if `Salibhdr\Typhoon\Telegram\Api` exists it returns `true`.

I checked the `autoload_classmap` file and notice that the composer includes all the classes under `Telegram` subfolder but not `Laravel` subfolder.

Why composer acts weird like this? why did it include one subfolder and not the other? It is something that I do every day and never seen anything like this.

I desperately need help. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where is your `composer.json` located?

Comment: @ChinLeung It's in `typhoon` folder

Comment: Have you checked if inside your `LumenServiceProvider` the class name matches the file name? Also, does it return true if you try with `LaravelServiceProvider`?

Comment: @ChinLeung I have done all the necessary checkings. And no it returns the same output with LaravelServiceProvider. both laravel and lumen service providers are extended from abstract TelegramServiceProvider. there are other classes in laravel folder an some of them are not included in the composer. but all the files in telegram folder in included

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue... I've tried it with your file structure and it's working just fine for me. Have you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: @ChinLeung Thanks for your response. yes I have run dumpautoload and I am exactly wondering why is this happening? everything looks normal to me. Is it possible that this issue is related to composer itself?

Comment: I do not think it's related to composer. As I've mentioned, I have the exact same file structure as you and it's working perfectly for me. There must be something that's not shown here that is causing it to not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to initialize `Salibhdr\Typhoon\Laravel\Providers\LumenServiceProvider` but in your composer it's `"SaliBhdr\\Typhoon\\": "src/"`.

Notice the capital `B` in your composer. PHP classes are case sensitive so you have to make sure it's either both lowercase or both uppercase.

Also make sure to run `composer dumpautoload` if you modify `composer.json`.

Comment: oh! I didn't notice that and I don't know why I did that mistake. Thank you so much for your time